# Should image size be defined in the img tag height/width attributes or in CSS?

Tags: html, css, image

Is it better coding practice to define an images size in the `img` tag's `width` and `height` attributes?

```
<img src="images/academia_vs_business.png" width="740" height="382" alt="" />
```

Or in the CSS style with width/height?

```
<img src="images/academia_vs_business.png" style="width:740px; height:382px;" alt="" />
```

Or both?

```
<img src="images/academia_vs_business.png" width="740" height="382" style="width:740px; height:382px" alt="" />
```

Comment: remember, specifying both height and width properties could lead to odd scaling issues. normally I would only specify the property which is required to make it fit in your design (typically width) the browser will then rescale the height to the correct proportions.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I'm going to go against the grain here and state that the principle of separating content from layout (which would justify the answers that suggest using CSS) does not always apply to image height and width.

Each image has an innate, original height and width that can be derived from the image data. In the framework of content vs layout, I would say that this derived height and width information is content, not layout, and should therefore be rendered as HTML as element attributes.

This is much like the `alt` text, which can also be said to be derived from the image. This also supports the idea that an arbitrary user agent (e.g. a speech browser) should have that information in order to relate it to the user. At the least, the aspect ratio could prove useful ("image has a width of 15 and a height of 200"). Such user agents wouldn't necessarily process any CSS.

The spec says that the `width` and `height` attributes can also be used to override the height and width conveyed in the actual image file. I am not suggesting they be used for this. To override height and width, I believe CSS (inline, embedded or external) is the best approach.

So depending on what you want to do, you would specify one and/or the other. I think ideally, the original height and width would always be specified as HTML element attributes, while styling information should optionally be conveyed in CSS.

Answer (score 47):

The historical reason to define height/width in tags is so that browsers can size the actual `<img>` elements in the page even before the CSS and/or image resources are loaded. If you do not supply height and width explicitly the `<img>` element will be rendered at 0x0 until the browser can size it based on the file. When this happens it causes a visual reflow of the page once the image loads, and is compounded if you have multiple images on the page. Sizing the `<img>` via height/width creates a physical placeholder in the page flow at the correct size, enabling your content to load asynchronously without disrupting the user experience.

Alternately, if you are doing mobile-responsive design, which is a best practice these days, it's quite common to specify a width (or max-width) **only** and define the height as `auto`. That way when you define media queries (e.g. CSS) for different screen widths, you can simply adjust the image width and let the browser deal with keeping the image height / aspect ratio correct. This is sort of a middle ground approach, as you may get some reflow, but it allows you to support a broad range of screen sizes, so the benefit usually outweighs the negative.

Finally, there are times when you may not know the image size ahead of time (image `src` might be loaded dynamically, or can change during the lifetime of the page via script) in which case using CSS only makes sense.

The bottom line is that you need to understand the trade-offs and decide which strategy makes the most sense for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Wait, if you don't have the image size ahead of time, how would you even add it to the CSS anyway?

Comment: @CamiloMartin CSS *and/or inline styles* that could be set programmatically. Also, images that change dynamically may have defined sizes, but only based on a specific page state that isn't known at page render time.

Comment: inline CSS would have the same effect of sizing the image, and so would external CSS once it is loaded, and that should not be an issue. I don't think you'll see un-styled markup

Comment: @AliGangji Inline CSS is bad practice, both for maintainability and for cacheability. Regarding unstyled markup / page reflow, it is a very real and common issue and is especially common with unsized images. Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content

Comment: @bmoeskau I'm not disagreeing that it's bad practice, just pointing out that CSS can have the same effect of sizing the image. Seeing un-styled content may be more common than I think. The only recent browser version that I've been able to see this in is Opera.

Comment: Well, leave it to google to break everything apart. Destroying what is common practice with bad practice. Like telling you to use inline styling over stylesheets. To use width and height tags on all images. Google broke the internet.

Answer (score 11):

While it's ok to use inline styles, your purposes may better be served by including an external CSS file on the page.  This way you could define a class of image (i.e. 'Thumbnail', 'Photo', 'Large', etc) and assign it a constant size.  This will help when you end up with images requiring the same placement across multiple pages.

Like this:

```
In your header:
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

Your HTML:
<img class="thumbnail" src="images/academia_vs_business.png" alt="" />

In css/style.css:
img.thumbnail {
   width: 75px;
   height: 75px;
}
```

If you'd like to use inline styles though, it's probably best to set the width and height using the style attribute for the sake of readability.

Answer (score 9):

Definitely not both. Other than that I'd have to say it's a personal preference. I'd use css if I had many images the same size to reduce code.

```
.my_images img {width: 20px; height:20px}
```

In the long term CSS may win out due to HTML attribute deprecation and more likely due to the growth of vector image formats like SVG where it can actually make sense to scale images using non-pixel based units like % or em.

Answer (score 8):

```
<img id="uxcMyImageId" src"myImage" width="100" height="100" />
```

specifying width and height in the image tag is a good practice..this way when the page loads there is space allocated for the image and the layout does not suffer any jerks even if the image takes a long time to load.

Comment: correct me if i am wrong but fire fox will not reserve screen space for your image. However I would use this method also. Unless I am making thumbnails. In that case i would set a css selector on a list

Comment: are you sure? because i have noticed and then adopted this method..

Comment: Doesn't the same happen with CSS height/width?

Comment: @user1767586 I've been told that no. It is better to specify on the img tag because of what ZX12R said

Answer (score 1):

**Option a.**
Simple straight fwd. What you see is what you get easy to make calculations.

**Option b.** Too messy to do this inline unless you want to have a site that can stretch. IE if you used the `with:86em` however modern browsers seem to handle this functionally adequately for my purposes.. . Personally the only time that i would use something like this is if i were to create a thumbnails catalogue.

```
/*css*/
ul.myThumbs{}
ul.myThumbs li {float:left; width:50px;}
ul.myThumbs li img{width:50px; height:50px;border:0;}

<!--html-->
<ul><li>
<img src="~/img/products/thumbs/productid.jpg" alt="" />
</li></ul>
```

**Option c.** Too messy to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `contentEditable` to allow rich text editing in my app. I don't know how it slips  through, but when an image is inserted, and then resized (by dragging the anchors on its side), it generates something like this:

```
  <img style="width:55px;height:55px" width="100" height="100" src="pic.gif" border=0/>
```

(subsequent testing shown that inserted images did not contain this "rogue" style attr+param).

When rendered by the browser (IE7), the width and height in the style overrides the img width/height param (so the image is shown like how I wanted it.. resized to 55px x 55px. So everything went well so it seems.

When I output the page to a ms-word document via setting the mime type application/msword or pasting the browser rendering to msword document, all the images reverted back to its default size.  I finally found out that msword is discarding the style and using the img width and height tag (which has the value of the original image size).

Took me a while to found this out. Anyway... I've coded a javascript function to traverse all  tags  and "transferring" the img style.width and style.height values into the img.width and img.height, then clearing both the values in style, before I proceed saving this piece of html/richtext data into the database.

cheers.

opps.. my answer is..  no. leave both attributes directly under img, rather than style.

Comment: Ah, see, here your problem is that you're using ms-word...