# width attribute of td is not overriding css width property

Tags: html, css, width

I have searched about this pretty much and still not able to understand the reasong for the behaviour. I have a td element with width attribute specified and I also have specified the width in css class. But the width in css class is reflecting, doesn't the width attribute of element take higher priority?

Sample code:

```
<table class="sample">
  <tr>
    <td width="70%" class="cell">First cell</td>
    <td class="cell">Second cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Css

```
table.sample {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}
td.cell {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 40%;
}
```

I understand that width attribute is deprecated and not advisable to use, I am trying to understand the behavior as I have to fix a similar issue, where I have many pages using the style td.cell but I need to override it in one page, I can go for style attribute that is one way, or define another style class.

Comment: I believe <td style="width:70%" class="cell"> would win out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [CSS 2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#preshint)

> 6.4.4 Precedence of non-CSS presentational hints
>
> The UA may choose to honor presentational attributes in an HTML source
>   document. If so, these attributes are translated to the corresponding
>   CSS rules with specificity equal to 0, and are treated as if they were
>   inserted at the start of the author style sheet. They may therefore be
>   overridden by subsequent style sheet rules. In a transition phase,
>   this policy will make it easier for stylistic attributes to coexist
>   with style sheets.

So CSS styles always out-rank presentational attributes in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

```
<table width="100%" class="sample">
  <tr>
    <td width="70%" class="cell">First cell</td>
    <td width="30%" class="cell">Second cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Css :-**

```
table.sample {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
td.cell {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write  `<td width="70%" class="cell">First cell</td>` and once Browser will parse
this line it will generate one column having property as width. but when you write like

```
<td style="width:70%" class="cell">First cell</td>
```

it will become one attribute of the `style` , Hence a kind of as you say inline CSS. So 
your External CSS cannot override it now.

try like this :-

```
<table class="sample">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:70%" class="cell">First cell</td>
    <td class="cell">Second cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Simply writing *Width* in mark up defines it as a property. So your Css is overriding this...

See this :- [Difference between property and attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/properties-and-attributes-in-html)
and this is the answer for your query :- [Should image size be defined in the img tag height/width attributes or in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414506/should-image-size-be-defined-in-the-img-tag-height-width-attributes-or-in-css#answer-2414940)

Comment: Yes this works, but what I need is the reason for the behavior mentioned in the question. If someone could point why is it correct / wrong will be helpful.

Comment: I have mentioned a very nice link ... go through the answer ..hope that will help you in understanding the difference. Moreover i will also update some points in my answer.

Comment: Hi Pranav thank you very much for the resources, it helped me get good understanding.