# Confused with HTML validation error

Tags: html, validation, semantic-markup

I have this code:

```
<img src="Media//Service//rightImage.jpg" alt="Watch Repair" width="380px" height="272px" style="float:right;" />
```

and the HTML validation tool on the [w3.org](http://w3.org) website I am using is saying that I cannot use a width of "380px" because:

> Bad value 380px for attribute width on element img: Expected a digit
>   but saw p instead. …ge.jpg" alt="Watch Repair" width="380px"
>   height="272px" style="float:right;" /> Syntax of non-negative integer:
>   One or more digits (0–9). For example: 42 and 0 are valid, but -273 is
>   not.

Does this mean  I should just delete the px part and it will run fine? I thought I have to define the width as pixels?

Very confused! Can anyone explain this to me? Thanks guys!

Comment: @Pekka웃 Any proof for that? The w3c says width attribute for img tag is absolutely valid, even in html5: http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/img.html#img.attrs.width

Comment: Where exactly have you found width properthy is deprecated? @Pekka웃

Comment: Also, you wrote the inline style. Which is not suggested unless is EXTREMELY unavoidable. @Pekka웃

Comment: @Lenin oh, you're right, it's not deprecated, not even in HTML 5: http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/img.html I restate, use of the CSS `width` property is generally encouraged; ideally, in an external class definition (which may not alway be feasible with images though)

Comment: If you check with markup validators. Some of them looks for the width and height of given images. @Pekka웃

Comment: @Lenin it's not a required property though.

Comment: Check this out @Pekka웃 :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640190/image-width-height-as-an-attribute-or-in-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to write "px" with width or height property of img

```
The width attribute specifies the width of an image, in pixels.
```

just write something like this

```
<img src="Media//Service//rightImage.jpg" alt="Watch Repair" width="380" height="272" style="float:right;" />
```

and the preferred way is to use `style` property to define these properties

```
<img src="Media//Service//rightImage.jpg" alt="Watch Repair" style="width:380px;height:272px;float:right;" />
```

Comment: Thank you. Not sure if it really matters which way. To me the way without using the style property seems simpler but that is just me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414506/should-image-size-be-defined-in-the-img-tag-height-width-attributes-or-in-css Worth following. @Mayron

Comment: You *must not* use `px` there. And the use of an external style sheet is preferred over `style` attributes, but no HTML specification recommends against `height` and `width` attributes when used to specify the actual, inherent size of the image (as opposite to rescaling).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its very trivial. You'd have to delete the px part and leave the numbers, they are always in pixels anyway.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_width.asp

A related thread for this which would help others: [Image width/height as an attribute or in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640190/image-width-height-as-an-attribute-or-in-css)

Another on the same is: [Should image size be defined in the img tag height/width attributes or in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414506/should-image-size-be-defined-in-the-img-tag-height-width-attributes-or-in-css)

Comment: Ah okay thank you, so after looking it up as well I finally found that it is done in pixels anyway so it is not needed.

Comment: w3schools should not be cited as any kind of authority, or at all, see http://w3fools.com

Comment: I am aware of [w3fools.com](http://w3fools.com). But I have quoted from the same topic of the OP. And the other SO links I have placed are worth reading. Dont just rely on w3fools, because its not complete. Just a ranter!

Answer (score 1):

By HTML5 rules, the [dimension attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#dimension-attributes), if used, must have values that are valid non-negative integers. No unit is needed, or accepted. The implied unit is CSS pixel. So yes, you should simply remove the `px` parts.

Answer (score 0):

remove 'px' from height & width attributes