# Image dimensions on browsers/devices

Tags: html, image

Let's say I have an image with actual size of 200x200 pixels. I insert it into a HTML page like this:

```
<img src="some.jpg" width="50" height="50">
```

Suppose there's no CSS styling for this image.
Will it be displayed consistently across all browsers and devices like a 50x50 image? Are there any exceptions?

Comment: w3 schools say's most popular browsers support width and height http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_width.asp

Comment: Some good responses [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414506/should-image-size-be-defined-in-the-img-tag-height-width-attributes-or-in-css)

Answer (score 1):

This style is supported among all of the major browsers (IE, Firefox, Opera, Safari, and Chrome)

Keep in mind that when doing this, the user is still forced to download the full size image before it is rendered in the size you specified! If it is a particularly large image, it may be wise to downscale it with an image editor before you upload it.

The user is still receiving the original file but the browser is altering it through its respective rendering methods.

The only exceptions to this rule, and this isn't necessarily due to browser rendering but may be helpful to keep in mind, is that HTML 5 no longer allows for you to adjust by percentage -- you can only adjust by pixels (as you already are)