# My Image will not stay set to a smaller size

Tags: html, css, styling

I have an image which I want to alter the size so it fits into the `<div>` that it sits within on my main homepage and also within my navbar along the top, however no matter what I try to apply to the CSS of the image, nothing changes, it still shows up huge.

**HTML for my index page div:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="grid-full containerHomepage">
        <div class="centered">SIGN UP TO HEAD-SMART<a class="noDecoration brain" href="signup.php"> NOW</a>
            <img class="mainLogo" src="images/HeadSmart.png">
        </div>
        <img src="images/homepage2.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.mainLogo{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

**HTML for my navbar:**

```
<nav>
  <!-- https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp -->
  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <a href="index.php" class="active"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>&nbsp; Home</a>
      <a href="about.php"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>&nbsp; About</a>
      <a href="contact.php"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>&nbsp; Contact</a>
      <?php  
        // The below is a small 'if else' statement which depending on whether a user is logged in or not, the menu items will differ
        // If logged in, then show the logout and the dashboard item
        // If not logged in, then show the login and signup button
        if (!isset($_SESSION['studentID'])) {
          echo "<a name='login-submit' href='login.php'><i class='fas fa-sign-in-alt'></i>&nbsp; Login</a>";
          echo "<a href='signup.php'><i class='fas fa-check-square'></i>&nbsp; Sign Up</a>";
        } else if (isset($_SESSION['studentID'])) {
          echo "<a href ='dashboard.php'><i class='fas fa-tachometer-alt'></i>&nbsp; Dashboard</a> ";
          echo "<a name='logout-submit' href='scripts/logout-script.php'><i class='fas fa-sign-out-alt'></i>&nbsp; Logout</a>";
        }
      ?>
      <a href="index.php" class="logo"><i class="fas fa-brain"></i></a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="menu2Function()">&#9776;</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**The size that I would like it to look in the navbar and on the index page(showing it with just an fa-icon for demonstration purposes):**
[image: Size I would like my image shown in the navbar and on the index page]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should image size be defined in the img tag height/width attributes or in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414506/should-image-size-be-defined-in-the-img-tag-height-width-attributes-or-in-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign a `width` and `height` property to the image tag itself, which is highly recommended. This tells the browser how large the image will be before it loads so it can prepare the space for it.

```
<img src="image.jpg" width="20" height="20" />
```

Comment: Hi Luze, that's worked perfectly, however why is it that I can set the height and width with in-line CSS compared to setting it externally in my `style.css` sheet? Shall I use `px` or `%`?

Comment: It's not really inline CSS in this case. It's just plain HTML to tell the browser which size the image will be before your external style.css or the image loads. This way the browser can prepare the space for it and make sure that the content of your website doesn't jump around when the image finally loads. This syntax uses `px` by default. `px` should be good for your logo, or icons in general.

Answer (score 1):

You should define the image dimensions within your `img` tag:

```
<img width="20" height="20" src="images/HeadSmart.png">
```

The values are defined in either *software pixels* (HTML 5) or *screen pixels* (HTML 4), so there is no need to add a unit (such as `px` in your CSS markup).

The advantage of defining dimensions in your HTML attributes is that browsers can style the image early on, even when the CSS file is not yet fully downloaded and processed. This way you prevent the so-called [Flash of unstyled content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) (FOUC).