# What are the width and height properties of a video element?

Tags: html, css, canvas, video

Take this `<video>` element:

```html
<video height=5 width=10><source src="..." type="video/mp4"></video>
```

What is the effect of setting `height=5 width=10`, or of subsequently setting these properties through JavaScript?

The only effect I'm aware of, through experimentation, is that the `width` and `height` properties are used as the size of the element in CSS pixels, if no size is otherwise specified through CSS.

In this way, the `<video>` element behaves like a `<canvas>` element. But on a `<canvas>` element, the `width` and `height` properties also serve another purpose: to set the dimensions of the 2D array of pixels that backs the canvas. This 2D array of pixels is then scaled to the display area of the canvas element (using `object-fit: fill` and `image-rendering: pixelated` by default).

But the `width` and `height` properties do not seem to set any kind of "backing array size" for the a video. When setting the `width` and `height` properties on a `<video>` element, it produces no observable effect on the pixelation of the video stream.

The number of pixels in the video seems to just come from the media stream itself -- as seen in the `videoWidth` and `videoHeight` properties of the `<video>` element, or in the `metadata.width` and `metadata.height` properties of a frame given to a `requestVideoFrameCallback` callback.

Unless explicitly set, the `width` and `height` properties have the value `0`, as reported by JavaScript. This is even when a video is playing. In contrast, the `width` and `height` properties `<canvas>` default to `300` and `150`, the true size of the 2D array of pixels that backs it.

[The MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement) describes these properties as

> `HTMLVideoElement.height`
>
> Is a `DOMString` that reflects the height HTML attribute, which specifies the height of the display area, in CSS pixels.
>
> `HTMLVideoElement.width`
>
> Is a `DOMString` that reflects the width HTML attribute, which specifies the width of the display area, in CSS pixels.

This seems untrue, though, since the default value `0` is given for videos that clearly do not have a zero display area. I also disbelieve this description because "the width/height of the display area, in CSS pixels" is perfectly settable through CSS, making these properties entirely redundant.

**So, what are the `width` and `height` properties of a `<video>` element? What purpose do they serve, other than being a redundant way to set CSS size?**

Comment: How did you arrive at zero in _"This seems untrue, though, since the default value 0 is given for videos that clearly do not have a zero display area.'_?

Comment: By querying the `.width` property of a playing video in JavaScript

Comment: Can you post the code you used for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same as the ones for `<iframe>`, or `<object>` and similar to `<img>`'s ones:

They serve as fallback to set the display size, which for inline replaced elements is calculated in this order (keep any found width or height if found before falling back):

1. CSS defined width + height
2. Attributes defined width + height
3. Aspect-ratio x previously selected width or height
4. Media defined width + height
5. 300 x 150px

(steps 3 and 4 are actually more complicated for media like SVG images).

```js
document.querySelectorAll("video").forEach( elem => elem.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm");
```

```css
.css-width {
  width: 200px;
}
.css-height {
  height: 200px;
}
video {
  border: 1px solid;
}
section {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <p>CSS width + CSS height + width attribute + height attribute</p>
  <video class="css-width css-height" width="10" height="10"></video>
  <p>CSS dimensions win</p>
</section>
<section>
  <p>CSS width + width attribute + height attribute:</p>
  <video class="css-width" width="10" height="10"></video>
  <p>CSS dimensions is used for width, attribute is used for height</p>
</section>
<section>
  <p>CSS width + height attribute:</p>
  <video class="css-width" height="10"></video>
  <p>Attributes are used</p>
</section>
<section>
  <p>CSS width only:</p>
  <video class="css-width"></video>
  <p>CSS width is used for width, height is set to the intrinsic aspect-ratio * width</p>
</section>
<section>
  <p>width attribute only:</p>
  <video width="10"></video>
  <p>Attribute width is used for width, height is set to the intrinsic aspect-ratio * width</p>
</section>
<section>
  nothing:<br>
  <video></video>
  <p>intrinsic dimensions are used</p>
</section>
```

However they do differ from `<img>` ones in that [at getting `<img>` ones](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#dom-img-height) will return the rendered CSS dimensions, while for `<video>` (and others), it will only return the value of the attribute, coerced to its type (`unsigned long` for `<video>`).

So if you don't set anything as attribute, indeed it will return `0`, whatever the rendered dimension.

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido, this is very helpful. This seems to confirm my feeling that these attributes are not actually _useful_, since CSS can perform the same job. My guess is that they only exist for historical reasons, and one should avoid setting or accessing them.

Comment: Setting them doesn't hurt and can actually help before CSS rules kicks in.

Comment: Hmm, based on your comparison with `img`, I found [this argument in favor of using these attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2414624/229792) - to tell the UA about the intrinsic dimensions of the media before it has loaded, creating a placeholder. CSS can then be used to _scale_ the image, using the aspect ratio defined by the `width` and `height` attributes. I'm semi-convinced. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: This is definitely useful for calculating the initial aspect ratio, which modern browsers no do based on these values.